# List of string is getting duplicated

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart

I am generating text fields dynamically and I am trying to get the contents of the text fields.

```
//I declared a list of string and generated it using the length of my product.
late final List<String> recovered; 

//the length of the products is 3
recovered = List.generate(products.length, (index) => "")); 

TextField(
   onSubmitted: (value) {
      recovered.insert(index, value);
      log("the value is $value");
      setState(() {});
   },    
   controller: myControllers[index],
   decoration: const InputDecoration(
       enabledBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
             borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey)),

     ),
),
```

I inserted 1,2,4 into the textFields generated by my listView Builder and got the following values
[1, 2, 4, , , ] instead of [1, 2, 4].

Comment: then why have you added this? ``recovered.insert(index, value);`` in the textfield onsubmit function.

Comment: To insert the values into the index for each string generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `insert` adds them to the list. I believe you want to replace them. For that, instead of

```
recovered.insert(index, value);
```

you need to do

```
recovered[index] = value;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ivo This works, any idea how I can get the individual strings since I can't be sure of the number of strings generated so I can't use recovered[0] and recovered[index] is giving me the first string

Answer (score 1):

on your `Submit` you need to check if the value is empty or not then add it to your list:

```
onSubmitted: (value) {
    if(value.isNotEmpty){
      recovered.insert(index, value);
      log("the value is $value");
      setState(() {});
    }
      
},
```